# how to use additionalProperties from a $ref file?

Tags: json, jsonschema, openapi

ive separated my JSON schemas into two files.

`person-input.json` (all properties that will be set by inputs.)

`person.json` (hold a ref to person-input.json but also have dateUpdate, dateCreated and DateDeleted).

This to separate the inputs from autogenerated date properties.

I do not want any posts to be able to add unwanted properties to my data, so i thought i would use `"additionalProperties": false` the problem is that if i use it in the `person-input.json` file it will not accept my "date" properties from the `person.json` file. And if i put it in the person.json file it doesn't stop random properties from being added. Is there a solution to this?

so this below dont work, have i missplaced the `"additionalProperties": false` ?

**`person.json`**

```
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "$ref": "./person-input.json"
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "dateCreated": {
        "name": "dateCreated",
        "type": "string",
        "description": "date created",
        "example": "2019-09-02T11:17:41.783Z"
        },
        "dateUpdated": {
          "type": "string",
          "nullable": true,
          "description": "date updated",
          "example": "2019-09-02T11:17:41.783Z"
        },
        "dateDeleted": {
          "type": "string",
          "nullable": true,
          "description": "date deleted",
          "example": "2019-09-02T11:17:41.783Z"
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`additionalProperties` cannot "see through" applicators like `allOf`, nor can it "see across" the use of `$ref`.

In order to fix this, you have to do SOME duplication of your schema in your outer most / top most schema, and remove the `additionalProperties: false` requirement from any child schemas.

`additionalProperties: false` works by applying `false` (which is a valid schema, which returns failure to validate) to values which do not match keys based on `properties` or `patternProperties` within the SAME schema object.

> Validation with "additionalProperties" applies only to the child
> values of instance names that do not match any names in "properties",
> and do not match any regular expression in "patternProperties".

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-validation-01#section-6.5.6 (draft-7)

So, if you need to copy all the properties you need to the top level schema. Yes this is not nice!

You can make it a little nicer by observing the fact that the values of a `properties` object are schemas, and as such may just be `true`, allowing the child schemas to actually DO the validation later.

Here's an example I'm going to be using in an upcoming talk:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "title": "MatchMakerExchange format for queries",
  "definitions": {
    "phenotypicFeatures": {
      "type": [
        "array"
      ]
    },
    "genomicFeatures": {
      "type": [
        "array"
      ]
    },
    "geneticsPatient": {
      "properties": {
        "phenotypicFeatures": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/phenotypicFeatures"
        },
        "genomicFeatures": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/genomicFeatures"
        }
      },
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "required": [
            "phenotypicFeatures"
          ]
        },
        {
          "required": [
            "genomicFeatures"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "regularPatient": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": [
            "string"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "patient": {
      "additionalProperties": false,
      "properties": {
        "name": true,
        "phenotypicFeatures": true,
        "genomicFeatures": true
      },
      "allOf": [
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/regularPatient"
        },
        {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/geneticsPatient"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

You may well ask... "Well, that's crazy. Can you fix this please?" - We did. It's called draft `2019-09`, and it's only recently been released, so you'll have to wait for implementations to catch up.

A new keyword, `unevaluatedProperties` depends on annotation results, but you'd still need to remove `additionalProperties: false` from child schemas.